# Return contents of p tag with space between spans in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to manipulate the DOM of a page and in one area I need to return the below:

```
<p class="styles_label__gDrbZ"><span><a href="/philadelphia">PHL</a></span><span>Review</span></p>
```

As

```
<p class="styles_label__gDrbZ"><span><a href="/philadelphia">PHL</a></span>&nbsp;   <span>Review</span></p>
```

I cannot seem to work out how to do this - any help much appreciated

Comment: did you try anything with jQuery? If yes, please post that code snippet as well.

Comment: What parts of that are static and what parts are dynamic? For instance, I assume the `__gDrbZ` part is dynamic. How about the `/philadelphia` part?

Comment: `p.styles_label__gDrbZ > span { margin-right:3em; }`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, two approaches which immediately I can think of is -

1. `:nth-child() Selector`
2. `.insertAfter()`

Below is the implmentation using the `:nth-child()`, selecting the first child which is the `<span>` tag within the `<p>` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("p span:nth-child(1)").append("&nbsp;");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="styles_label__gDrbZ"><span><a href="/philadelphia">PHL</a></span><span>Review</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked - thank you. I added the class to p to ensure it only affected that paragraph but it has worked perfectly - thanks.